# Unable to execute query in jasper studio query dialog. but the query is ok

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]

In jasper studio jdbc connection is ok. it can fetch table information from my database. but the problem is after execute the query it show error message. don't find any reason for this error. **Query****`SELECT  SUM(DEBIT_AMOUNT), SUM(CREDIT_AMOUNT), COST_CENTER_ID FROM  ACCTG_COST_CENTER_TRANS WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_ID= '10012' GROUP BY GL_ACCOUNT_ID`**

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a `ClassCastException`. Is it possible that field `COST_CENTER_ID` was declared as type `java.lang.Boolean` instead of `java.lang.String`?

Comment: NO I just removed Filter Expression from query dialog and it works.